# How to edit or update a banner in google adwords

Tags: google-ads-api, banner

This may be a very stupid question but i can't seem to figure out how i can edit / update a banner created in google adwords. The only thing I am able to do is click the "View full size display ad" link. Am I missing something or is it not possible to edit banners created in google adwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you can edit them! :-)

When you are in AdWords  click through your campaigns to view your ad groups, then click on the ad group you're interested in to see a list of ads contained in that ad group.

When you're looking at the list of ads in your ad group, by default you only see the "View full size display ad" link.  When you hover your mouse over the ad though, a small pencil/pen icon will appear.

When you click on that pencil/pen icon you get to edit the ad (you'll get a warning about what happens when you edit the ad - make sure you read and understand the consequences before editing!)